# strtoul unexpected hexadecimal conversion

Tags: c

I was expecting the following conversion from string to hexadecimal to fail, but it seems the conversion is valid

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    printf("%x", strtoul("abracadabra", NULL, 16));
    return 0;
}
```

prints "ab" !

Can someone explain me why ?

Answer (score 1):

[strtoul(3) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul)

> The strtoul() function converts the initial part of the string in nptr to an unsigned long int value according to the given base, which must be between 2 and 36 inclusive, or be the special value 0.

> The remainder of the string is converted to an unsigned long int value in the obvious manner, stopping at the first character which is not a valid digit in the given base.

As you see, `strtoul` does conversion until the first invalid character.

In this case, `ab`, which is the prefix of `abracadabra`, is valid as hexadecimal and `r` is invalid. This is why `ab` is converted to an integer.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. So I should check that the endptr argument is set to the end of the string if I want to be sure the full string is a valid hex number...

Comment: @user3719401 yes